# Socket io connecting server in java

Tags: sockets, java-websocket

Please give me an example on socket io connecting the server using java client and server. Describe socket io jar details also. I have googled but does not get the correct source code.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

Socket.IO Server is not a Java implementation.
Consequentially you can not have a Java server. 
You need to get some Java adaptation of Socket.IO, example:

[Netty Socket.IO Java Implementation](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio)

Fortunately, Socket.IO has a Java client implementation you can use.

[Socket.IO Java Client Implementation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java)

Both links have examples and demo's.